# How to invert colors in tkinter's canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, graphics

I'm curious if there's a way how to invert colors of canvas *directly* in it. I have seen PIL module which allows to work with image (as file), but I want to apply changes still visible inside of the canvas, which contains shapes.
e.g.:

```
import tkinter
canvas=tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill='blue', outline='red')
```

Can you please help me, what to do to invert colors?

Comment: This question is too broad, can you please provide more details. For instance, what does your canvas contains, images or just shapes? Do you want to invert the colors of the whole canvas? And a sample of code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great too.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think, the most logical way to invert colors is to apply it to whole canvas, or let's say part within specified coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I can only change colors of canvas items one at a time, but I can write a function that does all or parts of canvas. Example:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill='blue', outline='red')
canvas.create_line(100,100,160,160,fill='blue')

def invert_color(color):    # Invert color
    if type(color) == str: rgb = canvas.winfo_rgb(color)
    else: rgb = color
    rgb = (65535-rgb[0], 65535-rgb[1], 65535-rgb[2])
    tk_rgb = "#%04x%04x%04x" % (rgb)
    return tk_rgb

def invert_canvas(event):
    # Check or select canvas items:
    items = canvas.find_withtag('all')
    # Loop through canvas items
    for item in items:
        fill = canvas.itemcget(item, "fill")        # Get fill color
        if fill != '': fill = invert_color(fill)
        if canvas.type(item) in ['rectangle','arc']:
            outline = canvas.itemcget(item, "outline")  # Get outline color
            outline = invert_color(outline)
            canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=fill, outline=outline) # Set colors
        else:
            canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=fill) # Set colors

root.bind('<space>', invert_canvas)
```

Comment: Interesting solution... But how could I change also attributes (colors) of shapes which do not have outline (e.g. line)?

Comment: I think you'll have to check which types of widgets have which attributes and then change them depending on which type they are. Check type with `canvas.type(item)`.

Comment: Updated my example to accommadate 'rectangle', 'arc' and 'line'.

Comment: Hi, just a little question: It messes up when it comes to shapes with blank (not defined) fill. I would be glad for help...

Comment: Seems to work with simply checking if fill is set to anything: `if fill != '': fill = invert_color(fill)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: can u pls explain the arcane string tk_rgb = "#%04x%04x%04x" % (rgb)

Comment: The expression is code for formatting a string. In this case it takes each of the three color values in `rgb` and converts them into hex preceeded by a "#" sign. For a detailed explanation of string formatting see [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/).